Agora Token Authentication Error: Temporary Token Works but Server-Generated Token Fails
I'm using Agora's Web SDK to implement a video-calling feature in my app. When I generate a temporary token through the Agora Console, everything works fine, and users can join channels without any issues. However, when I generate a token from my server using Agora’s RtcTokenBuilder, I get an "unauthorized" or "authentication" error on the client side when trying to join a channel with that token.
Server Token Generation:
const express = require("express");
const { RtcTokenBuilder, RtcRole } = require("agora-access-token");

const APP_ID = "your-app-id";
const APP_CERTIFICATE = "your-app-certificate";
const PORT = 8080;

const app = express();

const generateRTCToken = (req, resp) => {
  const channelName = req.params.channel;
  if (!channelName) {
    return resp.status(500).json({ error: "channel is required" });
  }
  let uid = req.params.uid;
  if (!uid || uid === "") {
    return resp.status(500).json({ error: "uid is required" });
  }

  let role = req.params.role === "publisher" ? RtcRole.PUBLISHER : RtcRole.SUBSCRIBER;

  let expireTime = req.query.expiry || 3600;
  const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const privilegeExpireTime = currentTime + parseInt(expireTime, 10);

  let token;
  if (req.params.tokentype === 'userAccount') {
    token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithAccount(APP_ID, APP_CERTIFICATE, channelName, uid, role, privilegeExpireTime);
  } else if (req.params.tokentype === 'uid') {
    token = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(APP_ID, APP_CERTIFICATE, channelName, uid, role, privilegeExpireTime);
  } else {
    return resp.status(500).json({ error: "token type is invalid" });
  }

  return resp.json({ rtcToken: token });
};

app.get("/rtc/:channel/:role/:tokentype/:uid", generateRTCToken);
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
});

Client Code:
var client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "rtc", codec: "vp8" });
var options = { appid: "your-app-id", channel: "test-channel", token: "generated-token" };

async function join() {
  try {
    await client.join(options.appid, options.channel, options.token, null);
    console.log("Joined channel successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to join channel:", error);
  }
}

Problem:
The client receives an "unauthorized" or "authentication failed" error when using the server-generated token, but it works fine when using a temporary token from the Agora Console. This suggests that there’s an issue with the server-generated token, but I can’t figure out what’s wrong.
